# AWS OpsWorks "start_failed" status and no logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I would like to know how to debug new AWS OpsWorks instances. They fail to start the first time, and no log is generated.

The issue is fixed by stoping and restarting the instance. It only happens when a new instance is added to a layer.

[image: AWS OpsWorks]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possible causes are:

- Not enough resources space / memory
- Instance type not available in region
- AWS OpsWorks agent version.

SOLUTION

- Create a new instance with more resources in a supported region.
- Ensure the OpsWorks agent version is not causing issues by selecting a different earlier version.